# Runtime dependency because of visual studio minor upgrade

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, runtime

In my C++ project I use various open source libraries. I recently migrated from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2017. When I migrated, the latest version of the visual studio 2017 was version 15.4.2. Hence I recompiled all the open source libraries with this version of the visual studio. Now, I see that newer version of the Visual Studio is available. If I migrate to the newer version of the Visual Studio 2017, do I have to rebuild these open source libraries again? Or can they still work seamlessly? Would there be any runtime issues?

Answer (score 0):

No, it should still works fine.